# En Android Studio Zoom en WebView

Tags: android

al pulsar en una de las opciones del menu muestra una pagina web, la pagina se encuentra integrada en la aplición, como puedo hacer para cuando muestra la pagina se muestre en toda la pagina, y luego pueda hacer zoom para que se muestre manor yo menor ?

No se si al poner zoom se agranda tambien los menus, si eso es así, se pude hacer para que solo se pueda hacer zoom en la pagina htm.

en la pagina web tambien he puesto el codigo:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Posiblemente te hagan falta el siguiente código, el primero sirve para activar javascript y el segundo para activar el zoom en un webview.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```